# Android reference styles.xml from within strings.xml to set color of textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set the color of a particular part of a textview from within my strings.xml file, but I want to know if it is possible to use a pre-set value from my styles xml file to do this.

I can set the color of part of a string with `<font color="#ffff00">Text</font>`

Suppose I have a color "BadColour" in my xml file like so:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"> <item name="BadColour">#ff0000</item> </style>`

Can I reference BadColour from strings.xml? For example:

`<font color="BadColour">Text</font>. (This one doesn't work, of course.)`

I have tried different variations of `<font color="#ffff00">Text</font>` with the style name, such as `<font color="?attr/BadColour">Text</font>` to no avail.

Comment: you can create a attribute and use Spannable String to achieve it